# Makes sense to have your own OpenID Connect provider?

Tags: openid-connect

I have to implement local login (traditional mail/password login) and social login in a group of three websites (same subdomain).

Because I may eventually publish an API to be consumed by a mobile app, I am considering hosting my own OpenID connect provider (using a open source solution). Local login and the API would authenticate using this provider.

Is this a good idea? Any simpler and secure alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think using OIDC is fairly good for your case. Is a great idea in terms of architecture having user accounts separately from your apps, also imagine if you want to create mobile apps and log your users in, that's when OpenID shines.